# Batch Apex Unit Test: System.UnexpectedException: Error processing messages

Tags: batch, unexpectedexception

I had a batchable class `MyBatchable` whose unit tests have been running successfully for over 2 years and suddenly, they stopped working yesterday with error

```
Batch Apex Unit Test: System.UnexpectedException: Error processing messages
```

Looking at the debug log, it appears that the `start()` method fails to return any rows to `execute()` - even though it should return rows.

I looked at the other problem reasons in these answers

- Using [Big Objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253646/system-unexpectedexception-error-processing-messages-in-test-class-for-batch-ap) - *does not apply*
- [Sub class that implements `Database.Batchable`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200680/system-unexpectedexception-on-testing-batch) - *does not apply*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the `start()` method failed was the clue because ...

- I had recently introduced into the batchable start's QueryLocator the field `OrderItem.Product2Id`
- The batchable class was written as of V38.0
- The field `OrderItem.Product2Id` needs the `Database.getQueryLocator()` method to be executing with at least V40.0 to not cause the error.

Updating the batchable class to V56.0 solved the issue

*We could generalize that referencing a standard field not introduced until Vxx can not be used in a batchable's `getQueryLocator` method if batchable is running at Vxx-n, n >= 1 but I did not test this generalization.*